# Entrust Facade @role not working on Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I installed `Zizaco/entrust` (https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) with laravel 5.1 and added these in the `provider` and `aliases` array

```
'providers' => [
....
Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider::class,
]
'aliases' => [
....
'Entrust'   => Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustFacade::class,
]
```

I can access all the Entrust functionalities from controllers eg: `$user->hasRole('admin')` with no problems however when I try this in my view it doesn't work

```
@role('admin')
....
@endrole
```

It simply shows @role('admin') @endrole as html. So I tried

```
@if(\Entrust::role('admin'))
...
@endif
```

And I get

```
Call to undefined method Zizaco\Entrust\Entrust::role()
```

Do I have to perform any additional configuration or changes to make `@role` work? Or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to make sure, did you do a `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: Yes I did a `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Is `@role` a function of the blade templating engine? Is `->role()` or `::role()` a function of `Entrust`? From what I can see, the `Entrust` facade is working, you're just using it improperly...

Comment: I think `@role` is supposed to be a functionality of Entrust. It says in the documentation that "Three directives are available for use within your Blade templates." `@role` `@permission` and `@ability`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get `@roles('admin')` to work but this works

```
@if(Entrust::hasRole('admin'))
....
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for Laravel 5.1.31 LTS

1. So simply replace your file in the Vendors/Zizaco/entrust/src/Entrust/EntrustServiceProvider.php with the file below: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/blob/master/src/Entrust/EntrustServiceProvider.php
2. After that you can do php artisan view:clear
3. Then you can see error Call to undefined method Zizaco\Entrust\Entrust::ability()
4. That easy to solved Entrust::ability error you can replace file Vendors/Zizaco/entrust/src/Entrust/Entrust.php with https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Zizaco/entrust/master/src/Entrust/Entrust.php